# MS SQL -- Add another restriction from a third table

Tags: sql-server

The question I have is I have to add another restriction:
All the listed items have to be green. So i found the colour of the items are in the table xitem.
 Where should I add that comment to my current code?

My current code is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM xsale, xdept 
WHERE xsale.deptname IN 
  (
    SELECT deptname 
    FROM xsale 
    WHERE xsale.deptname=xsale.deptname 
    AND deptfloor <> 1
  )
```

Comment: Your code, as-is, doesn't make much sense. Can you you share sample data and desired results?

Comment: I would recommend getting out of the habit of using a comma for inner joins, primarily for code clarity. Here's a question that details this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467662/the-difference-between-comma-and-join-in-sql

Comment: So now i have selected all the products which are not sold on the first floor. I have to add another restriction namely all items have to be green. And those items can be found in the table xitem

Comment: Using aliases would make this a million times clearer. Your subquery is pointless here because without aliases you have basically said where 1 = 1. Without table definitions and desired output this question is really not answerable.