# What is the difference between JOIN and SELECT?

Tags: sql

So I have two tables called Product and Product_Review where Product_Review holds reviews for products that are already defined in the Product table with their attribute C_CODE. We were given an assignment to join these two tables by their Product ID so naturally I went with:

```
SELECT * 
FROM PRODUCT INNER JOIN 
     PRODUCT_REVIEW 
     ON PRODUCT.C_CODE=PRODUCT_REVIEW.C_PRODUCT_ID
```

However we were given the answer afterwards with a different method without any joins being performed:

```
SELECT * 
FROM PRODUCT, PRODUCT_REVIEW 
WHERE PRODUCT.C_CODE=PRODUCT_REVIEW.C_PRODUCT_ID
```

My question is what is the difference between these two commands and if there isn't any difference then why do we need the join command when we can just perform a basic select?

Comment: There is no difference. The second one is extremely outdated syntax though

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467662/the-difference-between-comma-and-join-in-sql